# When deploying Next.js to Vercel using Mongoose to fetch data I'm getting a blank screen

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, vercel, next.js14

I have the following `layout.tsx` file:

```
import { ClerkProvider, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { DevMode, Footer, LogRocketInit, Nav } from "./components";
import "./global.scss";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { User, findUser } from "@/mongo/functions/user";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
    title: "Commerce Karma",
};

export const runtime = "nodejs";

if (typeof setImmediate === "undefined") {
    global.setImmediate = function (fn) {
        setTimeout(fn, 0);
    };
}

export default async function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    const user = await currentUser();
    let isSignedInUser = false;

    let userStore: User[] | null = null;

    if (user) {
        isSignedInUser = true
        userStore = await findUser({filters: {userId: user.id}})
    };

    return (
        <ClerkProvider
            appearance={{
                variables: {
                    colorPrimary: "rgb(59,121,173)",
                },
            }}
        >
            <html lang="en">
                <body className={inter.className}>
                    <LogRocketInit userProp={JSON.stringify(user)}/>
                    <Nav isSignedIn={isSignedInUser}/>
                    {children}
                    {userStore[0]?.isDevUser ? <DevMode /> : null}
                </body>
            </html>
        </ClerkProvider>
    );
}
```

After lots of debuging I have detirmed  that `userStore = await findUser({filters: {userId: user.id}})` is the problem. On local (`npm run dev` and `npm run build && npm run start` everything is fine, but when deployed on Vercel I'm getting a blank screen across all routes of my application.

Here is my `.swcrc` file:

```
{
    "jsc": {
        "parser": {
            "syntax": "typescript",
            "tsx": true
        },
        "experimental": {
            "plugins": [["swc-plugin-add-display-name", {}]]
        }
    }
}
```

My `next.config.js` file:

```
/* eslint-disable */

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
                    {
                        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT,OPTIONS",
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        value:
                            "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization, id, filters, Api-Key",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];
    },
    webpack: (
        config,
        { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }
    ) => {
        nextRuntime = "nodejs";
        return config;
    },
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Finaly my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "commerce-karma",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.29.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@lexical/react": "^0.13.1",
    "@lexical/utils": "^0.13.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
    "aws4": "^1.12.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "crypto-random-string": "^5.0.0",
    "http-method-enum": "^1.0.0",
    "jose": "^5.1.3",
    "lexical": "^0.13.1",
    "logrocket": "^7.0.0",
    "logrocket-react": "^6.0.3",
    "mongodb": "^6.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.2.1",
    "next": "^14.1.3",
    "next-client-cookies": "^1.1.0",
    "nuqs": "^1.15.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-simple-wysiwyg": "^3.0.2",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1",
    "ssl-checker": "^2.0.9",
    "svix": "^1.5.0",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookies": "^0.7.10",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/logrocket-react": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/node": "20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.7",
    "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.7",
    "eslint": "^8.41.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "swc-plugin-add-display-name": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

- All pages are blank
- Only Next.js scripts are included in the DOM not the content in the `main` tag
- REmoving the find call fixes the issue

I'm using Next.js 14.1.3 and Mongoose 8.2.1.